# Complex text mining in R with matching words from 2 lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, text-mining, matching

Well i created 2 list :

```
expensive <- c("wine","watch","book","books","bottles","whisky")
g1 <-c(df$gifts)
```

(I have of course more than 6 words in my "expensive list" but it's just for the example.)
My idea is to look at matching number to keep only the observation where match >1

So i created the Match column like that :

```
all_gifts <- data.frame(gift = g1) %>%
  mutate(
    Match = str_to_lower(gift) %>%
      str_split(" ") %>%
      map_int(~sum(.x %in% expensive))
  )
```

It works well, but i have a problem for book/books. In fact, i'm only interested in some kind of books' gifts : those without a description because i cannot know if they're expensive or cheap then.

So this i what i have :

| Gift | Match |
| --- | --- |
| book | 1 |
| book from Jules Vernes | 1 |
| chemistry books | 1 |
| 2 books | 1 |

And this is what i'd like to have instead :

| Gift | Match |
| --- | --- |
| book | 1 |
| book from Jules Vernes | 0 |
| chemistry books | 0 |
| 2 books | 1 |

Comment: It would probably help to `dput(df)` the input here. 2 books  implies match >1. Anyway, looks like you want to subset or index match >1 after  `~sum(.x %in% expensive)) %>%` that I imagine is just counting...

Comment: Oh yeah my bad you're completely right i can count the number of words when gift contains "book","books" and delete those who have a count >2